# aws linux in `exist?': no implicit conversion of Array into String

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, aws-code-deploy

When I am installing codedeploy-agent in aws linux getting this error

/usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:83:in `exist?': no implicit conversion of Array into String (TypeError)

```
      if File.exist?(path)
                     ^^^^
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:83:in `set_dev'
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger/log_device.rb:18:in `initialize'
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger.rb:587:in `new'
    from /usr/share/ruby3.2/logger.rb:587:in `initialize'
    from ./install:43:in `new'
    from ./install:43:in `<main>'
```

[image]

Comment: It means that your `path` variable is referring to an array whereas `File.exist?` expects a string, i.e. you are passing the wrong kind of object somewhere.

Comment: basically I have just install ruby on my ec2 instance for code-deploy-agent

Comment: Just had the same issue on an instance running ruby3.2, on another instance running ruby2 it works without a problem. Very likely related to the ruby package version.

Comment: can you please share how you update ruby3.2 to ruby2?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in the installer in Ruby 3+. You may want to report it to AWS

Comment: It also has this method `def supported_ruby_versions ['3.0', '2.7', '2.6', '2.5', '2.4', '2.3', '2.2', '2.1', '2.0'] end` so using 3.0 might be enough

Comment: I'm seeing this happen with Amazon Linux 2023 when installing codedeploy agent.  Issue is not seen in Amazon Linux 2.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. was fixed after downgrading ruby from 3.x to 2.x

1. Uninstall existing ruby using **yum remove ruby**
2. Install the gpg keys required for rvm installation using:
   **gpg2 --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB**
   3)Install rvm using **curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable**
   4)After installation,
   use below commands
   **rvm get head**
   **rvm list known** --- it will list available packages
   install using command : **rvm install 2.0.0**
   check version using ruby -version

For more details refer : https://rvm.io/

Comment: after installing getting error ruby version not found

Comment: ruby -v shows ruby version

Comment: use command ruby -version